# Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR: Getting Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Logon'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I am new in SignalR and I am trying to develop simple chat application using signalR with ASP.NET MVC 3. I have done following coding with [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR (C#)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) reference.

**ChatHub**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, ChatUser> _users 
        = new Dictionary<string, ChatUser>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        var user = _users.Values.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ClientId == Context.ConnectionId);

        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("User is not logged in");
        }

         return Clients.All.message(user.Name, message, TimeStamp());
    }

    public void Logon(string clientName)
    {
        if (clientName.Length > 10)
        {
            throw new Exception("I prefer short names.");
        }

        if (_users.Any(x => x.Key == clientName))
        {
            throw new Exception("User name is already taken, please select a different one.");
        }

        _users.Add(clientName, new ChatUser { ClientId = Context.ConnectionId, Name = clientName });

        Clients.Caller.name = clientName;

        Clients.All.loggedOn(clientName, TimeStamp());
    }

    public Task Logout()
    {
        var user = _users.Values.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ClientId == Context.ConnectionId);

        if (user != null)
        {
            _users.Remove(user.Name);
           return  Clients.All.loggedOff(user.Name, TimeStamp());
        }

        return null;
    }



    public IEnumerable<ChatUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return _users.Values.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }

    private static string TimeStamp()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }
}
```

**ChatUser Class**

```
public class ChatUser
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**IndexView.chtml**

SignalR Chat

```
        <div id="info" class="round">
            <h1>
                SignalR Chat</h1>
            <form id="startform">
             Enter your name:
            <input type="text" id="name" />
            <input type="button" id="btn_login" class="button" style="margin-top: 25px;" value="Start chatting" />
            </form>
            <div id="login_error" style="margin-top: 100px;" class="error">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="chat">
            <div style="height: 50px;">
                <div>SignalRChat</div>
                <div id="logout">
                    <a href="" id="btn_logout">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="users-box right round2">
                <strong>Users in chat:</strong>
                <ul id="users">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-box round2">
                <div id="messages">
                    <ul id="message-list">
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <form id="chatform">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="msg" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" width="100px">
                            <input type="button" id="btn_send" class="button" value="Send" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         var onlineUsers = null;
        var userList = [];
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        var getUsers = function () {
            chat.server.getUsers().done(function (users) {
                onlineUsers = users;
                updateUserList();
            });
        };

        var updateUserList = function () {
            $('#users li').remove();
            userList = [];

            $.each(onlineUsers, function () {
                var listItem = $('<li>{0}</li>'.format(this.Name));
                $('#users').append(listItem);

                userList[this.Name] = User(this.Name, listItem);
            });
        };

        var send = function () {
            if ($('#msg').val() !== '') {
                chat.server.Send($('#msg').val());
                $("#msg").val('');
            }
        };

        var login = function () {
            if ($('#name').val() !== '') {
                clientName = $('#name').val();

                chat.server.Logon(clientName, function () {
                    $("#info").toggle();
                    $("#chat").toggle();
                    $('#msg').focus();
                    getUsers();
                }).fail(function (e) {
                    $('#login_error').html(e);
                });
            }
        };

        var logout = function () {
            chat.server.Logout();
        }

        // Callbacks from server
        chat.client.message = function (user, msg, time) {
            $('#message-list').append('<li class="message">{0} {1}: {2}</li>'.format(time, user, msg));
            $("#messages").prop({ scrollTop: $("#messages").prop("scrollHeight") });
        };

        chat.client.loggedOn = function (user, time) {
            $('#message-list').append('<li class="info">{0} {1} logged on</li>'.format(time, user));
            getUsers();
        };

        chat.client.loggedOff = function (user, time) {
            $('#message-list').append('<li class="info">{0} {1} logged off</li>'.format(time, user));
            getUsers();
        };

        chat.client.userTyping = function (user) {
            userList[user].typing();
        };

        // Form events
        $("#btn_send").click(function () { send(); $('#msg').focus(); });
        $("#btn_login").click(function () { login(); });
        $("#btn_logout").click(function () { logout(); });
        $('#chatform').submit(function () { send(); return false; });
        $('#startform').submit(function () { login(); return false; });


        // Logout when user closes browser
        window.onbeforeunload = function () { chat.server.Logout(); };

        // Start chat
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("Connected");
        });

        $("#chat").toggle();
        $('#name').focus();

    });

</script>
```

But I am getting following when I am trying to call `Logon` method of `ChatHub`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'Logon'

Anyone help me where I am wrong in above coding with SignalR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When communicating with server methods via JavaScript with SignalR the server methods are referenced as Camel Cased unless specified via the `HubMethodName` attribute.

If you want to continue using your current code you can fix it in two ways.

1. On your server side Hub put `[HubMethodName("foo")]` above each
   method with the correct name.  So Logon would be:

   `[HubMethodName("Logon")]
   public void Logon(string clientName)
   {
   ...
   }`
2. in the JavaScript script you can do:

   `chat.server.logon(...);`

Keep in mind you'd have to apply either one of these approaches to all methods (via #1) or all communications to the server (via #2).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried with your first solution but I am getting new error 'Logon' method could not be resolved. On Logon call fail(function (e) {
                        $('#login_error').html(e); is executing.

Comment: Found error ... wrong syntax used for calling Logon method.. updated logon method calling syntax,,, chat.server.Logon(clientName).done(function () { $("#info").toggle(); $("#chat").toggle(); $('#msg').focus(); getUsers(); }).fail(function (e) { $('#login_error').html(e); }); Now it's working perfectly.. and Thanks for your help... your solution working perfectly.